# Cordova-Wikitude - Plugin or Functions for Capturing Images from Camera Feed

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, wikitude, camera-view, wikitude-sdk

Are there standard plugin options or existing functions to support capturing images from the camera feed in a Cordova with Wikitude implementation?  We’ve been researching using the Wikitude Plugins API with Cordova but have not found a solution that will enable the camera view to be shared concurrently during this scenario.  We’ve seen other 3rd Party Plugin implementations that support this process when Cordova or Wikitude is not included.  We are trying to provide a cross platform object recognition feature with our app.  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the captureScreen api of the Wikitude Plugin?

Comment: Thanks Alex!  I appreciate the info.  Does the captureScreen API in the Wikitude Plugin include web view content (i.e. buttons, augmentations, etc) along with the screen image?  We need to exclude web view content in this part of our service.  Thanks again!

Comment: CaptureScreen takes 4 parameters, successCallback, errorCallback, bool includeWebView and imagePathInBundleorNullForPhotoLibrary. If you set the third one to false you should get the camera without webview contents.

Comment: Many thanks again Alex!  We'll follow up on the captureScreen API options.  We were also experiencing a screen flash during our testing which was intrusive to the user.  We have a requirement to run our image capture almost-continuously (i.e. capture the image based on some interval) in the background.  Do you know if the screen flash can be turned off when using the captureScreen API?

Comment: This could be because the plugin stores the screenshot directly into the storage. What you could try is to modify the captureScreen method of the wikitude plugin in a way where they are stored asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks again Alex!  I will share your comments with our developer that's working on this part of the service.